# object must implement IConvertible error in linq query to select two rows

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have an Excel sheet , I need to fetch two columns values - I have written a Linq query -

Error:

> contextSwitchDeadLock was detected error at line

Query:

```
select new { Description = typeDescription.Description ,
VehicleKey = typeDescription.VehicleKey });
```

how can i fix this error - i want to fetch two coulmns value from the same Excel sheet , from a single linq Query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its due to null values

try like this.

```
select new { Description = Convert.ToString(typeDescription.Description) , 
    VehicleKey = Convert.ToString(typeDescription.VehicleKey) });
```